# Refine Query using joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, refactoring

How a query can b done using joins. i am new in database. this query is working fine.. 
but i want to make it more rubust

```
   $query = "SELECT student_id 
FROM students
WHERE student_id
IN (
    SELECT student_id
    FROM class_students
    WHERE class_id
        IN (
            SELECT class_id
            FROM class_course
            WHERE teacher_id =". $_SESSION['teacher_id']."))";
```

is there anyother way to do that

Comment: Yes. See JOINs. That's what they're for.

Comment: Here is a simport tutorial on [`joins`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and a [visual representation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `IN` can be converted to proper joins:

```
SELECT s.student_id 
FROM students s
JOIN class_students cs ON cs.student_id = s.student_id
JOIN class_course c ON c.class_id = cs.class_id
WHERE teacher_id = ?
```

Note that I have removed the (irrelevant) application language specifics (perl?) to leave just the SQL that answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "select students.student_id
from class_course left outer join class_students on 
        class_course.class_id = class_students.class_id
    left outer join students on 
        class_students.student_id = students.student_id
where class_course.teacher_id = ". $_SESSION['teacher_id']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $query = "SELECT s.student_id 
FROM students s
    INNER JOIN class_students cs
        ON s.student_id = cs.student_id
    INNER JOIN class_course cc
        ON cs.class_id = cc.class_id
            AND cc.teacher_id =". $_SESSION['teacher_id']."))
```